# How to find the variance of a linear regression estimator?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

How can I calculate the variance of [image] and [image] estimator for a linear regression model where [image]?

Is there a function in R for finding the point estimator like mean, variance of these two estimator?

My data is

```
fit <- lm(log(TV.Drna$ppDr)~log(TV.Drna$ppTV),data=log(TV.Drna))
```

Comment: Where is the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: if you do `summary(yourModel)` it will print this stuff

Comment: Your call to `lm` looks very strange. Why don't you first create a data.frame with log of your data, then call this data.frame via the `data` argument of `lm`?

Answer (score 1):

You are after the `vcov` function. After creating a simple **reproducible** data set

```
set.seed(1)
dd = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y= rnorm(10))
```

and creating a `lm` object

```
m = lm(y ~ x, data=dd)
```

You can access the variance-covariance matrix via

```
R> vcov(m) 
            (Intercept)        x
(Intercept)     0.11394 -0.02662
x              -0.02662  0.20136
```

You can access point estimates of your parameters via

```
coef(m)
```

Other useful statistics are accessed via `summary(m)`.